# How to specify GUEST ONLY access endpoint in Open API?

Tags: openapi

We know that in Open API v3 we can define security schemes for each endpoint/http method requests. For example:

1. Sanctum token is required for accessing services.

   ```yaml
   /services
     get:
       security:
       - Sanctum: ['services:read']
   ```
2. Sanctum token with ability to see hidden product is required,
   but anybody can access common products

   ```yaml
   /products
     get:
       security:
       - Sanctum: ['products:read:with-hidden']
       - {}
   ```
3. Everybody can access status checks.

   ```yaml
   /status
     get:
       security: []
   ```

How do you define security scheme for an endpoint/request accessible only and only if the Authorization Header is omitted from the request?
For example, authentication endpoint:

4. Only guest can access this, (guest = no authorization header supplied).

   ```yaml
   /users/authenticate
     post:
       security: ???
   ```